# Why doesn't list.get(0).equals(null) work?

Tags: java, list, null, arraylist

The first index is set to null (empty), but it doesn't print the right output, why?

```
//set the first index as null and the rest as "High"
String a []= {null,"High","High","High","High","High"};

//add array to arraylist
ArrayList<Object> choice = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(a)); 

for(int i=0; i<choice.size(); i++){
   if(i==0){
       if(choice.get(0).equals(null))
           System.out.println("I am empty");  //it doesn't print this output
    }
}
```

Comment: A trick:
`System.out.println(Arrays.asList(null,"High","High","High","High","High"));` does what you want without all that extra code.  I say its the "same" because you probably didn't know you could print nulls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is change,

```
if(choice.get(0).equals(null))
```

to

```
if(choice.get(0) == null))
```

Comment: No problem, see cletus' answer for a more in depth reason why it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

You want:

```
for (int i=0; i<choice.size(); i++) {
  if (i==0) {
    if (choice.get(0) == null) {
      System.out.println("I am empty");  //it doesn't print this output
    }
  }
}
```

The expression `choice.get(0).equals(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException` because `choice.get(0)` is `null` and you try and call a function on it. For this reason `anyObject.equals(null)` will *always* return `false`.

Comment: While returning true for  `equals(null)` violates the API contract, it is in fact quite possible.